# Form's Select Box Selected Option is not being captured via PHP email

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using a form within my website and all the fields are being captured and sent via PHP as an email but the select box options are not being captured or sent.

My form's code is:

```
<form id="contact" class="contact-form" name="contact" method="post" novalidate>
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-input-group" id="form-container">
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" size="30" placeholder="Name">
      <i class="fa fa-male" id="form-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group text-container test box" id="form-container">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" id="form-icon"></i>

      <select id="selector" class="selector" name="selector">
        <option value="hide" selected>Select One</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="form-btn form-btn-fill" id="contact-submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

My PHP is:

```
<?php

    $to = "hello@website.com";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];

    $subject = "Website Contact Form Submission";

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $selector = $_REQUEST['selector'];

    $body = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">
    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" />

    </head>
    <body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0;\">

    <!-- FORM CONTENT SECTION -->
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=\"#ffffff\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;\" class=\"section-padding\">
            <table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"500\" class=\"responsive-table\">
                <tr>
                    <td align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 12px 12px 5px 12px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #aaaaaa; border-top: 1px solid #3eb489;\">Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=\"left\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px; padding: 0 12px 12px 12px;\">$name</td>
                <tr>
                    <td align=\"left\" style=\"padding: 12px 12px 5px 12px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #aaaaaa; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;\">Selector</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align=\"left\" style=\"font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 16px; padding: 0 12px 12px 12px; border-bottom: 1px solid #3eb489; line-height: 24px;\">$selector</td>
                </tr>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "Return-Path: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What does `var_dump($_REQUEST)` show?

Comment: I tried $_POST and still nothing :(

Comment: @Barmar How would I try your method with my PHP? Do I add as is?

Comment: var_dump of $_POST or $_REQUEST should show you everything from the form/submit

Comment: Just put it somewhere in the script. It's just a debugging statement, it displays the contents of the variable.

Comment: where's ur form action?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Forms have a default action to post to the same URL of the page.

Comment: @roxy-p You know that `$selector` will just be the number `1` or `2`, not the word `One` or `Two`, right?

Comment: @Barmar Yes i do :)

Comment: this form is working fine, when you echo $selector u get 1 or 2 I just tested as it is

Comment: Can you show var_dump or print_r details here ?

Comment: It is working my side. I have no idea why it is, but I think the $_POST did it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced $_REQUEST with $_POST and that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

You can just change in your html

```
<select id="selector" class="selector" name="selector">
    <option value="hide" >Select One</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would removing the `selected` option solve this? That just sets the default option, it has no effect once the user chooses something else.

Comment: Agreed, would have no effect on the "posted" form variables